# How to make Libreoffice build smallest as possible?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm planning to use only LibreOffice to convert files from one format to another.
E.g
`soffice --headless --convert-to doc --outdir D:\output D:\input\filename.docx`
So e.g I completely don't need GUI support ,etc.
What flags/options should I use during ./autogen , make to minimize build process as much as possible ?

Comment: Use a normal build. You won't save much with custom build options and will just chase bugs that nobody else is seeing. Unless you really know what you are doing you should not use custom build options.

Comment: Hi moggi, thx for the response. Looking at ur profile I see that ur perfect person to ask about that stuff ;). Thing is I would like to compile it with modified gcc version coming from afl-fuzz and be able to fuzz first all functionality related with conversion from one format to another.
Did you guys try to compile it with afl-gcc ? Maybe fuzz it with afl ?

Comment: Yes. One of the LibreOffice developers uses afl to fuzz the import filter. There is no separate conversion functionality, all the conversions go through an import into the document model and an export from the document model. You can read some details about that and some of the other work at https://conference.libreoffice.org/assets/Conference/Aarhus/Slides/CaolanMcNamaracoverity.pdf